# Sed to fetch text between 2 words

Tags: unix, sed

How to fetch text between `"total":`  and `, "issues"` , in short I need to fetch `3004` number from the below file.

```
Cat test1

{"expand":"schema,names","startAt":0,"maxResults":2,"total":3004,"issues":
```

What would be exact command to fetch `3004` from the above file?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Are you trying to parse JSON?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `sed`, than

```
sed -e 's/.*\"total\":\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'
```

should do the trick.
If you want to parse JSON, use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `unix` I am guess you don't have `grep` with `PCRE`. You can get away with the following `perl` one-liner, though as others have recommended it is best to use a `json` parser.

#### `perl:`

```
$ echo '{"expand":"schema,names","startAt":0,"maxResults":2,"total":3004,"issues":' | 
perl -nle 'print $1 if /(?<="total":)([0-9]+)(?=,"issues")/'
3004
```

If you don't have many `"total":` then following should suffice:

```
$ echo '{"expand":"schema,names","startAt":0,"maxResults":2,"total":3004,"issues":' | 
perl -nle 'print $1 if /(?<="total":)([0-9]+)/'
3004
```

#### `grep with PCRE:`

```
$ echo '{"expand":"schema,names","startAt":0,"maxResults":2,"total":3004,"issues":' | 
grep -oP '(?<="total":)[0-9]+'
3004
```